Error Converting Angular 10 to 14: Type Incompatibility in patchValue Method
I am in the process of upgrading an Angular project from version 10 to 17. While upgrading to Angular 14, I encountered several errors throughout the project. One of the issues arises from the following code:
if(this.rentBaseData.mandateUnitRent.rentBasesGuaranteeDetail && this.rentBaseData.mandateUnitRent.rentBasesGuaranteeDetail.length > 0){
    this.rentBasesGuaranteeDetail.controls = [];
    this.rentBaseData.mandateUnitRent.rentBasesGuaranteeDetail.forEach(elem => {
        let obj = this.addRentbaseGuarantee();
        obj.patchValue(elem);
        if(elem.guarantor.length > 0){
            let guarantee = elem.guarantor.map(x => x.id);
            obj.get('guarantor').patchValue(guarantee.toString());
        }
        this.rentBasesGuaranteeDetail.push(obj);
    });
}

The addRentbaseGuarantee method is defined as follows:
addRentbaseGuarantee(id = "", rentBasesId = "", type = "", typeText = "", castlePurpose = "", amount = "", endDate = "", guarantor = "", operationFlag = 'updated') {
    return this.fb.group({
        id: [id],
        rentBasesId: [rentBasesId],
        type: this._form.addDropDownFormGroup(type, typeText),
        castlePurpose: [castlePurpose],
        amount: [amount, [BixValidator.onlyNumber('Enter valid data')]],
        endDate: [endDate],
        guarantor: [guarantor],
        operationFlag: operationFlag
    });
}

The rentBasesGuaranteeDetail (i.e., this.rentBaseData.mandateUnitRent.rentBasesGuaranteeDetail) is a list of objects of the following class:
export class MandateUnitRentBasesGuaranteeDetail { 
    constructor(
        public id = "",
        public rentBasesId = "",
        public type: SingleDropdownObject = new SingleDropdownObject(),
        public castlePurpose = "",
        public amount = "",
        public endDate = "",
        public guarantor: SingleDropdownObject[] = [],
        public operationFlag = ""
    ) {}
}

Therefore, the elem object will not contain the typeText value, but since it is provided with an empty string as a default value, it should be taken as such. However, I get the following error on the line obj.patchValue(elem);:
Argument of type 'MandateUnitRentBasesGuaranteeDetail' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<{ id: string; rentBasesId: string; type: Partial<{ id: string; name: string; }>; castlePurpose: string; amount: string; endDate: string; guarantor: string; operationFlag: string; }>'.
  Types of property 'guarantor' are incompatible.
    Type 'SingleDropdownObject[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

How can I resolve this type incompatibility issue? Any guidance on how to properly handle this type mismatch would be greatly appreciated.

please share more code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

I guess there is no way except for fixing the missing properties in 'elem' parameter.

Since Angular 14 form controls can now be strongly typed, I think this is the reason why your application is now failing.
Before then, FormControl created through the use of the FormBuilder would have a type of any regardless of the value, but now the type is infered from the default value.
In your case, that would mean that the guarantor field from the FormGroup built in the addRentbaseGuarantee used to had a type of any, but is now typed as a string, which I believe is why you cannot patch it's value with an array of SingleDropdownObject anymore.
You could go past this problem by adding strong typing to the guarantor FormControl and providing an empty array as a default value instead of an empty string :
addRentbaseGuarantee(id = "", rentBasesId = "", type = "", typeText = "", castlePurpose = "", amount = "", endDate = "", guarantor = [], operationFlag = 'updated') {
    return this.fb.group({
        id: [id],
        rentBasesId: [rentBasesId],
        type: this._form.addDropDownFormGroup(type, typeText),
        castlePurpose: [castlePurpose],
        amount: [amount, [BixValidator.onlyNumber('Enter valid data')]],
        endDate: [endDate],
        // You can provide a new FormControl to add complex typing.
        guarantor: new FormControl<SingleDropdownObject[]>(guarantor),
        operationFlag: operationFlag
    });
}

Keep in mind that I don't have a full vision on your application and the use of the addRentbaseGuarantee so changing its prototype might not be an appropriate solution.
